# Why do I get an "undefined reference" link error for a static member variable?

Tags: c++

I have this code

**File:  Gnome.cpp**

```
#include "Living.h"

class Gnome : public Living {
public:
    Gnome();
    void drawObjects();
};


Gnome::Gnome()
{
  // **** The line below is where the error occurs **** 
  spriteImg = new Sprite("graphics/gnome.bmp");  
  loaded = true;
}
```

**File:  Living.h**

```
#include <iostream>  
#include "Sprite.h"


using namespace std;

class Sprite;

class Living {
protected:
    int x,y;
    static Sprite *spriteImg; //= NULL;
    bool loaded;

    void reset();

public:
    Living();
    ~Living();
    int getX();
    void setX(int _x);
    int getY();
    void setY(int _y);
    void virtual drawObjects() =0;
};
```

But when I try to build it, the linker shows this error:

> Undefined reference to Living::spriteImg

I have no idea how to fix this -- what's the problem?

Comment: This is fundamentally a C++ issue (as stephelton's answer shows), not specific to game development, and is consequently a bit off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 6):

You declared spriteImg, but never defined it. In living.cpp, try adding the following:

```
Sprite* Living::spriteImg = NULL;
```

Since you declared it, the compiler allows you to reference it, and expects that the linker will resolve the reference. Since there is never a definition, the linker can't do so, and it complains.

**Edit:** if you would like to learn more about what's going on here, research topics such as "compilation units," "compiling," "linking," and "static class variables in C++."

Comment: also, if you are already using C++11 then it should be `Sprite* Living::spriteImg = nullptr`