# Undefined reference with static variables in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following files with the below mentioned class definition:

```
//File1.hpp
class A{
  public:
  static std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> var1;
};

//File2.cpp
#include "File1.hpp"
static std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> CreatVar1() {
  std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> var;
  var[std::make_pair(0, 0)] = 0;
  return var;
}
std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> A::var1 = CreateVar1();
void main()
{
  std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> pair1;
  pair1 = std::make_pair(1, 2);
  std::map <std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned > a;
  a[pair1] = 3
  A::var1 = a;
  //It calls File3.cpp after this
}

//File3.cpp
#include "File1.hpp"
void method1()
{
  std::map <std::pair <unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> b=A::var1;
}
```

However, when I do so I get the following error in File3.cpp.....

```
undefined reference to `A::var1'
```

Is there a way by which I may correct this error?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076114/why-do-i-get-an-undefined-reference-link-error-for-a-static-member-variable), but there the programmer forgot to initialize. I have already done the initialization; something else is wrong.

Comment: Do you have #ifdef / #define at the top of your File1.hpp or not ?

Comment: @40two: no, no ; static attribute must not be declare in header file. There will be multiple definitions if he does that.

Comment: Another comment putting the word `static` in front of functions for static linkage in C++ is deprecated use an unnamed namespace for this.

Comment: @40two I tried that but since the header file file1.hpp is getting used in multiple files...it gives me error

Comment: Ok then it looks like you are messing something with your file safe guards then.

Comment: @AliceEverett: add at the top of your file1.hpp: `#ifdef FILE1_HPP #define FILE1_HPP` and `#endif` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: @40two: Please look up the *One definition rule*.

Comment: @AntiClimacus Sorry for misconception, I know that it's bad practice. I just wanted to see what would be the results of doing it in order to get more info on the issue

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Sorry it is nowhere even remotely linked to the question asked..can u please justify as to why did u think so?

Comment: @40two: No, it was deprecated in C++03 but it has been undeprecated in C++11 because there is absolutely no reason not to do it.

Comment: @AliceEverett: It has _everything_ to do with the question asked. Perhaps you should look it up also.

Comment: Everyone, header guards have _nothing_ to do with this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did look at it..but this question is not even remotely connected with the other question: the QP in the other question forgot to initialize..but in my question i have already done the initialization

Comment: @Alice: It's the same issue. The initialization/definition _doesn't count_ if you don't pass it to the compiler. Similarly, if you defined the static member in crayons on your bedroom wall, I'd point you to a question about defining it properly.

Comment: @AliceEverett: Try do copy and paste the code in 3 different files like your comments indicate, fix all the typos, and then compile & link like Richard suggests in his answer. I suspect you posted something different to what you are actually doing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you very much for the info, I didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

rather than typing this:

```
g++ File2.cpp
g++ File3.cpp
```

type this:

```
g++ File2.cpp File3.cpp
```

(replace g++ with whichever c++ compiler you are using)

By default, the c++ compiler will attempt to compile all source files on the command line and then link them into a complete program. You can suppress this behaviour by adding the -c command line option.

Comment: This is what I tried..but still I am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Having corrected the spelling mistakes and added a semicolon that was missing, it now compiles and links.

```
#include <map>

class A{
 public:
 static std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> var1;
};

static std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> CreateVar1() {
  std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> var;
  var[std::make_pair(0,0)]=0;
  return var;
}

std::map<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> A::var1 = CreateVar1();

int main()
{
std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> pair1;
pair1=std::make_pair(1,2);
std::map <std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned > a;
a[pair1]=3;
A::var1 = a;

//It calls File3.cpp after this
    return 0;
}

void method1()
{
std::map <std::pair <unsigned, unsigned>, unsigned> b=A::var1;
}
```

Comment: Within the same file it works...but with different files..it is still giving errors

Comment: @AliceEverett: You need to put the definition and initialization of `A::var1` into a `.cpp` file, never in the header.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Yes that's what I did..see 40two discussion regarding the same in the comments

Comment: @AliceEverett: In that case I suspect you forgot to include the object file defining `A::var1` when linking the final executable, but that isn't clear from your question.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Since main() is the first function which gets called...and it defines the static member..and then this static member is being called in File3.cpp..then why am i getting the error...as by definition static member's value once defined should remain there..right

Comment: @AliceEverett: You probably forget to include `File3.cpp` when linking, see Richard Hodges's answer.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier I did include File3.cpp while linking

Comment: Apparently you did not.